# Reactjs Axios not going to catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I got the following function but when it encountered an error it didn't event go to catch it just went straight to then. Note that this was working I was just trying to force the catch

```
const AddMainItem = HPSMainObject => {
  let data = JSON.stringify(HPSMainObject);

  const request = axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: getMainUrl(
      "web/lists/GetByTitle('" +
        MAINITEMGENERALINFO.mainItemRelatedObject.mainList.title +
        "')/Items"
    ),
    data: data,
    headers: INTERNALCONFIG.PostHeader
  });

  return request.then(result => result.data.d).catch(error => error);
};
```

I called it using this, can you advise whats the best practice?

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    let self = this;
    AddMainItem(self.state.HPSMainObject)
      .then(function(AddMainItemResult) {
        console.log("its working");
      })
      .catch(function(errorMessage) {
        console.log("Error AddMainItem: ", errorMessage);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
.catch(error => error)
```

...converts rejected Promises to Promises that resolve to the error. It's the equivalent of doing this in synchronous code:

```
try {
  doSomething();
} catch (error) {
  return error; // The function is no-longer throwing
}
```

It seems what you're wanting to do is:

```
.catch(error => { throw error; })
```

...but that's redundant. Just omit the catch, and the caller's `catch` will kick in.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand it correct when you say omit catch you mean I just remove the catch in my handleSubmit  function and maintain the .error in the AddMainItem?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Either that, or make sure you re-throw after catching.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake! I don't know how I forgot that it continues to return a promise chain.

Comment: Thanks. but just a question what if I want to make the one calling function(handleSubmit) get the error message?

Comment: Because I am planning to call other function when that function gets an error

Comment: You can throw a new error: `.catch(error => { throw new Error('Some custom message'); })` if you mean you want to wrap the error with something having a friendlier error message.